# JsonNullable is not serializing its value with Jackson

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to use `JsonNullable<String>` to distinguish between the absence of a value and `null`. When I serialize my Java object, `User`, the `JsonNullable<String>` field is serialized as a JSON object with value

```
{"present":false}
```

I'm expecting it to print `{}` since I initialized the field with `undefined`.

Here's my class

```
public class User { 
  @JsonProperty("userId")
  private JsonNullable<String> userId = JsonNullable.undefined();

  //set and get
  //tostring
}
```

and a small driver program where I actually set a value within the `JsonNullable` field.

```
User user = new User();
user.setUserId(JsonNullable.of("12345"));

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());

String expectedData = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(user);
System.out.println(expectedData);
```

This prints

```
{"userId":{"present":true}}
```

But I expected

```
{"userId":"12345"}
```

In other words, I expected the value wrapped within the `JsonNullable` to be serialized into the JSON. Why are `JsonNullable` and Jackson behaving this way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the [wiki](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/jackson-databind-nullable/blob/master/README.md) instructs, you need to register the corresponding module (in addition to any others you have):

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
objectMapper.registerModule(new JsonNullableModule());
```

Answer (score 9):

Add the following configuration in Spring Boot:

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public JsonNullableModule jsonNullableModule() {
        return new JsonNullableModule();
    }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly fine. Also this is the required dependency: 
`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind-nullable</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.0</version>
</dependency>`

Answer (score 1):

Registering the `JsonNullableModule` is the correct solution. But I just want to point out that `JsonNullable` doesn't play well with openapi-generator. We generate client APIs from the backend controller annotations. The required, nullable annotations on `@schema` didn't work for us (on a Kotlin data class). We went back with using `Optional<T>?` and worked out perfectly with out any extra annotations needed.