# How to omit null field from Swagger/OpenAPI in ResponseEntity?

Tags: json, spring, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

I'm trying to omit null values in my ResponseEntity.

My controller looks something like this:

```java
@RestController
public class FooController {

    //fields
    //constructor

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<CreateFooResponseV10> createFoo(@Valid @RequestBody CreateFooRequestV10 foo, HttpServletRequest request) {
        //some minor logic
        return new ResponseEntity<>(aFooResponseV10Builder()
                .withFirstName(foo.getFirstName())
                .withLastName(foo.getLastName())
                .withTestField(NULLABLE_OBJECT)
                .build(), ...);
    //I generated the builders from the output classes openapi-generator provided
    }
    // more stuff...
}
```

When `NULLABLE_OBJECT` is equal to `null` I expect the field to be omitted from the response like this:

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe"
}
```

But I either get these responses, depending on what I've tried so far:

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "testField": null
}
```

or

```
{
   "firstName": "John",
   "lastName": "Doe",
   "testField": {"present":false}
}
```

I generate my request/response objects (`CreateFooResponseV10` and `CreateFooRequestV10`) with the use of [openapi-generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator-maven-plugin)

Here is my redacted `api.json` file:

```
{
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "info": { ... },
  "servers": [ ... ],
  "paths": {
    "/foo": {
      "post": {
        ...
        "requestBody": {
          "description": "Foo to be created",
          "content": {
            "application/foo+json;version=1.0": {
              "schema": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/CreateFooRequest_V1_0"
              }
            }
          },
          "required": true
        },
        "responses": {
          "201": {
            "description": "Foo is successfully created",
            "headers": { ... },
            "content": {
              "application/foo+json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/CreateFooResponse_V1_0"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          ...
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "CreateFooRequest_V1_0": {
        "required": [
          "firstName",
          "lastName"
        ],
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "firstName": { ... },
          "lastName": { ... },
          "testField": {
            "description": "...",
            "type": "string",
            "nullable": true
          }
        }
      },
      "CreateFooResponse_V1_0": {
        "required": [
          "firstName",
          "lastName"
        ],
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "firstName": { ... },
          "lastName": { ... },
          "testField": {
            "description": "...",
            "type": "string",
            "nullable": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see in both the request and response `testField` is not required and can be nullable.
So when testField is `null` it should be hidden from the response, but when it contains some date it should be shown of course.

I've tried overriding jackson's ObjectMapper bean as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58800892/3845362). Didn't work.

I've tried adding `spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=non_null` to the `application.properties`. Didn't work.

What I think should work is adding `@JsonIgnore` above `testField` of the generated classes, but I don't know if this is something needed to be done manually (for each schema component, can be a lot of manual work for something that is generated) or if this can be configured in the plugin somewhere.

Thanks in advance.

---

extra info

OpenAPI 3.0.1

Maven 3.6.3

Java 11.0.2

jackson-databind-nullable 0.2.1

openapi-generator-maven-plugin 4.2.2

Answer (score 17):

You can set the following in `application.properties`

```
spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion = NON_NULL
```

See [Customize the Jackson ObjectMapper](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper)

**Note:** To make use of this, you need to `@Autowire` the `ObjectMapper`, and not manually create it

Comment: Thanks, also the solution by Popov works, but in that case I had to fix also the conversion in json text of the dates in OffsetDateTime generated by default settings.

Comment: its not working for me with spring boot version 2.1.4
I use application.yml file
spring:
  jackson:
    default-property-inclusion: NON_NULL

Comment: @MiGo It works for me only if I autowire the ApiClient Bean instead of creating with `new`.

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: Using the classes generated by openapi and making certain fields nullable, all I had to do was add this spring config

Answer (score 8):

You can generate the model classes with additional class annotations using OpenApi generator.
Just need to include this in your maven plugin:

```
<configOptions>
   <additionalModelTypeAnnotations>
@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude(com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
   </additionalModelTypeAnnotations>
<configOptions>
```

see other config options here:
https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/spring/

Answer (score 5):

Try registering the following bean in your spring context. It should override default bean

```
@Bean
public HttpMessageConverters httpMessageConverters() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL)
    return new HttpMessageConverters(
            new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(mapper));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It's working.  I am also searching if someway we can add config properties while open API code generator so that no need to include bean.

Answer (score -3):

Try this code. I tested and it works.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/testws")
public class TestWS {
    @RequestMapping(value = "test", method = { RequestMethod.POST,
            RequestMethod.GET }, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<TestBean> test(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
        TestBean testBean = new TestBean("John", "Doe", null);
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .body(testBean);
    }
}

@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
class TestBean {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String testField;

    public TestBean() {

    }

    public TestBean(String firstName, String lastName, String testField) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.testField = testField;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getTestField() {
        return testField;
    }

    public void setTestField(String testField) {
        this.testField = testField;
    }

}
```

Json response:

```
{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe"}
```

Comment: Not helpful, as described in the question the request&response objects are automatically generated with Swagger and therefore adding a manual annotation is not possible.